# How is it in Spark, reduce and aggregate are the same

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, definition

•   In math, we think of reduce when a denominator and numerator share the same multiplier and that multiplier is “reduced” to a simpler concept (as in “is divisible by”).
•   In math, an aggregate, while similar, does not produce the same value in a reduced form, instead, aggregate will produce a single value that is representative of the whole, the whole being a derived state of the data and used primarily for statistical purposes.  For example: “Out of 10 sales people, we generated $60000 in capital sales.”

•   https://docs.databricks.com/sql/language-manual/functions/reduce.html
•   https://docs.databricks.com/sql/language-manual/functions/aggregate.html

Apparently in Apache Spark, reduce means the same thing as aggregate as explained by Databricks.

Can someone clarify the difference or explain how these two words (reduce and aggregate), with a perceptibly different context, can be considered to be the same?

Answer (score 0):

From the doc. you posted, you can find the explanation of the `reduce`, that is

> This function is a synonym for aggregate function.

Comment: I'm not sure my question above was clear.   If there is an equivalent to reduce being the same as aggregate, I can vaguely see a connection but in my mind, these are two separate concepts. at least, mathematically, these are separate.   SQL and Python tend to be mathematical in nature.   If that is true, then the context of a method needs additional attention.   Possible the Spark folks should have a bug listing here that indicates how these concepts are different and reduce should be limited to common denominator rather than more like "Group By"/"Aggregate".

Comment: Hmm, perhaps by reduce, the meaning refers to how an aggregate can "reduce" the number of rows.